# Why can't Mathematica simplify $\left(e^{t/m}(gm)^{1/k}\right)^{-k}$?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

It seems Mathematica can't simplify this

```mathematica
Simplify[(e^(t/m)*(g*m)^(1/k))^(-k)]
```

The result is

[image: (e^(t/m) (g m)^(1/k))^-k]

I think it should be

[image]

Comment: Use [`PowerExpand`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PowerExpand.html).

Comment: @Domen Yes. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You have to define the domain of the definition of the parameters in order to simplify the expression. Another useful command here is `Refine`:
`Refine[(Exp[t/m]*(g*m)^(1/k))^(-k), t > 0 && m > 0 && k > 0 && g > 0]`

Comment: @JohnTaylor But, for example, `m` could smaller than `0`.

Comment: @Y.zeng : you may just require m to be real.

Comment: @JohnTaylor `Refine[(Exp[t/m]*(g*m)^(1/k))^(-k), t > 0 && Element[m, Reals] && k > 0 && g > 0]` would produce another result, which is not so simplified.